# Unable to get contents of a tag of in xml file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a xml file channels.xml containing something like this.

```
<StreamingChannelList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
<StreamingChannel>
<Source xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07">
<a:directUrl>
 rtsp://10.232.15.90/PSIA/Streaming/Channels/F36AFF8A-79A0-4C80-BED7-4EF795B4EDB0
</a:directUrl>
</Source>
</StreamingChannel>
</StreamingChannelList>
```

I need to get content of a:directUrl tag and i wrote following javascript but unable to get the tag content.can anybody tell me what's wrong in the code(specially last 4 lines)?
FYI :using Safari browser on windows

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","channels.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

var StreamingChannel=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("StreamingChannel");
var Source=StreamingChannel[0].getElementsByTagName("Source");
var directUrl=Source[0].getElementsByTagName("a:directUrl");
document.write("<td>"+directUrl[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td>");
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Safari has problems with the prefixed element name, `a:directUrl`.

What you need is the special prefix version of `getElementsByTagName`, namely `getElementsByTagNameNS`, that has as a first parameter the URI of the namespace.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagNameNS

So the call would have to be

```
var directUrl = Source[0].getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07", "directUrl");
```

and then it works, at least in Safari and Firefox.
Now the problem is that I haven't been able to test in IE, because IE refuses to do HTTP requests, but rumour has it that IE doesn't know about `getElementsByTagNameNS`. Therefore you will need something like

```
var directUrl;
if (document.getElementsByTagNameNS)
  directUrl = Source[0].getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07", "directUrl");
else 
  directUrl = Source[0].getElementsByTagName("a:directUrl");
```

Not sure if that will work though; this may need some work. Like I said, I can't get IE to work here.

Comment: changed the call to                                                var directUrl = Source[0].getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07", "directUrl");

Comment: After changing the call to `var directUrl = Source[0].getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07", "directUrl");`, i am able to get the tag content. thanks to @Mr Lister

Comment: i found out that it is possible to get the a:directUrl content using tag's absolute position. `directUrl=StreamingChannel[i].getElementsByTagName("Source")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;`